# How to display label for bi-direct link/path/line in D3js force directed layout

Tags: d3.js, force-layout, topology

I'm trying to draw a network topology using D3sj force directed layout. I did a basic topology with link and node. However, now i want to show the interface name for each link on each node as the following picture. Could you guys guide me how i can do that?

Thank you in advance!

P/S I attached my topology here![1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZegO9.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should present the javascript that you have already written, and explained what it does do, and what is missing. Having said that, I recently finished work on a similar project to what you describe, so had the following results handy.

Does this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/munderwood/9S4uT/) do what you are attempting?

There are two key components. The first is in defining the text elements (here I append them to an SVG element):

```
var text = svg.selectAll('text')
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append('text')
        .text(function (d) { return d.name });
```

Here I'm assuming that the `nodes[]` array contains objects with a `.name` property that is to be displayed.

The second component is to translate the text elements to their appropriate positions, inside the `tick` handler:

```
function tick () {
    text.attr('transform', function (d) {
        return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
    });
    // Other code for nodes and links
}
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/munderwood/9S4uT/) for a complete working example, including commented code that should allow you to add images at the nodes if you want to try to reproduce your sample image more closely.